# How to update source table when matched or not matched?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-merge

I have 2 table, my goal is when I upload file(the file contain more than one data) I already insert file data in table history, the first step is I want to compare history table to table called EDC table if an uploaded file contains data that exist in EDC then update history table (history table contain column isExist) if matched I want to update history and if not matched I want to update column isExist to 0

```
MERGE EDC AS trgt
USING (SELECT kcndh.Nomor_Kartu_Kredit,kcndh.Nama_CardHolder, kcndh.IsExistEDW FROM History kcndh WHERE kcndh.nama_file = '1233.csv')S
ON trgt.Nomor_Kartu_Kredit = Nomor_Kartu_Kredit AND trgt.Nama_Pemegang_Kartu = Nama_CardHolder
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        S.IsExistEDW = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE set
        S.IsExistEDW = 0;
```

I got error

> An action of type 'UPDATE' is not allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement.

Is there any way to compare and update without using merge or how do I achieve my goal without comparing upload value in history table one by one to EDC table?

Comment: The definition of "NOT MATCHED" means a matching row wasn't found.... so there is no row to update. You need to show some sample data and desired results to further clarify what you require, because its not clear to me.

Comment: if row not matched i want to update souce table, is that posible using merge?

Comment: You can't update the source table with a merge, only the target table.

Comment: Do you have your Source and Target tables reversed by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, you can only update the target table with a `MERGE` statement (not the source table).

However, you can do this with a simple `UPDATE` statement (there is no need for a `MERGE` statement):

```
UPDATE History SET IsExistEDW=CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM EDC e
        WHERE e.Nomor_Kartu_Kredit = h.Nomor_Kartu_Kredit 
        AND e.Nama_Pemegang_Kartu = h.Nama_CardHolder
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM History h
WHERE h.nama_file = '1233.csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join to check existance of another table.

```
update History 
set    IsExistEDW = case when kcndh.Nomor_Kartu_Kredit is null then 0 else 1 end
from   History kcndh
       left join EDC trgt
       on trgt.Nomor_Kartu_Kredit = kcndh.Nomor_Kartu_Kredit 
       and trgt.Nama_Pemegang_Kartu = kcndh.Nama_CardHolder
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works as expected:

```
;with SOURCE as 
    (select .....
    ),
    TARGET as
    (select .....
     where [Released] = 1
    )
merge into target
    using source
        on source.[ID] = target.[ID] 
    when matched then  -- update monitored idle time
        update set 
        target.[Minutes] = datediff(minute, source.[Queued], getdate())
    when not matched by source then
        update set
        target.[Released] = 0  -- stop monitoring
    when not matched by target then -- insert new monitored task
        insert ([Minutes], 
                [Released])
        values (datediff(minute, source.[Queued], getdate(), 
                1);
```